# How to Have a Border Show Up Only When a Push Button is Clicked in PyQt5

Tags: python, button, tabs, pyqt5

here is the code I am using:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Win(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PipBoy'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 480
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.setFixedWidth(800)
        self.setFixedHeight(480)

        self.table_widget = StatsTabs(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)

        self.setStyleSheet("background:#141A15 ; color:#65F68C")


class StatsTabs(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)

        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QWidget()
        self.tab3 = QWidget()
        self.tab4 = QWidget()
        self.tab5 = QWidget()

        self.tabs.resize(800, 480)

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "Status")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2, "S.P.E.C.I.A.L.")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab3, "Skills")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab4, "Perks")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab5, "General")

        # Create first tab
        self.setTab1()

        self.setTab2()

        # Add tabs to widget
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.uni_font = QFont("Monofonto", 14)
        self.setStyleSheet("background:#141A15 ; color:#65F68C")
        self.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton{border-color:#65F68C}")

        QApplication.setFont(self.uni_font)

    def setTab1(self):
        self.tab1.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label1 = QLabel("")
        self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.label1)
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1.layout)

    def show_skills_desc(self, index):
        self.skill_desc.setText(self.lines[index])

        self.skillspic = QPixmap("statsimgs/" + str(index) + ".png")
        self.skillspiclabel.setPixmap(self.skillspic)

        self.skill_desc.setStyleSheet(
            "border:1px solid;border-color:#65F68C")

    def setTab2(self):
        self.tab2.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        skills_list = ["Barter", "Big Guns", "Energy Weapons", "Explosives", "Lockpick", "Medicine",
                       "Melee Weapons", "Repair", "Science", "Small Guns", "Sneak", "Speech", "Unarmed"]
        self.button_list = []

        self.skill_desc = QLabel("")
        self.skill_desc.setWordWrap(True)
        self.skill_desc.setGeometry(0, 0, 480, 240)
        self.skill_desc.setFixedWidth(480)
        self.skill_desc.setFixedHeight(100)

        self.skillspiclabel = QLabel()
        self.skillspiclabel.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.skillspiclabel.setFixedHeight(200)
        self.skillspiclabel.setScaledContents(True)
        self.skillspiclabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.tab_label = QLabel("STATS")
        self.tab2.layout.addWidget(self.tab_label, 0, 0)

        with open("skills.txt") as f:
            self.lines = f.readlines()

        for i in range(13):
            button = QPushButton(skills_list[i])
            button.setFixedHeight(35)
            self.button_list.append(button)
            self.tab2.layout.addWidget(self.button_list[i], i+1, 0)
            self.button_list[i].clicked.connect(
                lambda checked, c=i: self.show_skills_desc(int(c)))

        self.tab2.layout.addWidget(self.skillspiclabel, 1, 1, 7, 1)

        self.tab2.layout.addWidget(self.skill_desc, 7, 1, 6, 1)

        self.tab2.setLayout(self.tab2.layout)


def show_window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = Win()

    root.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


show_window()
```

In the S.P.E.C.I.A.L. tab, I want a border to show up around a button when it is clicked, and disappear when another button is clicked. (So that only one button is highlighted at a time.)

Is there a way to do this?

Also, does anyone know how to change the styling of the tab menu at the top of the window?

Comment: From what you're describing, it seems that you may not need *checkable* buttons that are actually part of an *exclusive* [QButtonGroup](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html), so that whenever one button of a group is pressed, the previous one (if any) is then unpressed. Besides: 1. don't create a layout with a parent widget if you're going to set the layout on *another* widget; 2. use [`enumerate()`](//docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate); 3. you already have the reference to the button (it's `button`), no need to get it again from the list; 4. `c` (or `i`) is already an integer.

Comment: Finally: please ask only *one* question per post. Also, your question about the "tab menu" (which is actually named "tab bar") is too vague.

Comment: Ok thank you for the advice! Can you just elaborate on what I would need enumerate() for?

Comment: `for i, skill in enumerate(skill_list):` `button = QPushButton(skill)`

Comment: Okay and do you mean not to use the Win class for 1 in your first comment? Also, I meant to ask: how do I set the background color, border color, etc. for the tab bar? I  really appreciate the help!

Comment: 1. If you're setting the layout for `self.tab2`, it's completely pointless to do `self.tab2.layout = QGridLayout(self)`. You either do `self.tab2.layout = QGridLayout()`, otherwise `self.tab2.layout = QGridLayout(self.tab2)` and *do not* call `setLayout()`. 2. As already said, you can only ask one question per post, and comments are not intended for unrelated questions. That said: [read the documentation examples](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar). Also, don't overwrite `self.width` and `self.height`, as they're dynamic properties of all QWidgets.